# How to make sure method have certain type in ruby

Tags: ruby

As you probably know, ruby, like most scripting languages is dynamically-typed. How can I make sure parameter passed to my method is instance of specific class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `is_a?`:

```
def your_method(param)
    if param.is_a? String
        # it's a string
    else
        # not a string
    end
end
```

Or, if you have lots of classes to check, a `case` statement:

```
def your_method(param)
    case param
    when String
        # it's a string
    when Array
        # it's an array
    when Rational
        # it's a rational
    # ...
    else
        # it's not any of these classes
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Check its type.

That said, why? In general you should be caring about its duckitude, not its type. I'm generally suspicious when something is tied to its type rather than its messages.

Comment: +1. Specifically, `parameter.respond_to?(:method_i_want)` being preferred to `parameter.is_a?(ClassIWant)`.

Comment: Error checking. Let's say your method calls for a string and some idiot programmer passes a number. Not possible with strongly-typed languages, possible with likes of Runy, PHP or Python.

Comment: @DariuszG.Jagielski I don't understand what you're trying to say. I said to check its type, but again, it's preferable to check its interface.

Answer (score 1):

It is up to caller to provide the argument of correct type. It is common in Ruby to raise `ArgumentError` if the method is called with an argument of unsupported type. Example:

```
def do_something_with_a_number(number)
  raise ArgumentError, "you have to provide a number" unless number.is_a?(Fixnum)
  ...
end
```